# Is it possible to 'uncurry' a forall quantifier?

Tags: haskell, currying, type-level-computation, data-kinds, higher-rank-types

Suppose we have a type constructor f that takes two types, by means of a DataKinds-promoted pair.

```
forall (f :: (ka, kb) -> *)
```

I can then implement a function `forward`, which is like `curry` for the `forall` quantifier:

```
forward :: forall (f :: (ka, kb) -> *).
           (forall (ab :: (ka, kb)).     f ab) ->
           (forall (a :: ka) (b :: kb).  f '(a, b))
forward x = x
```

However, the reverse function is problematic:

```
backward :: forall (f :: (*, *) -> *).
            (forall (a :: *) (b :: *). f '(a, b)) ->
            (forall (ab :: (*, *)). f ab)
backward x = x
```

GHC 8.0.1 gives the error message:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘ab’ with ‘'(a0, b0)’
      ‘ab’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          backward :: forall (ab :: (*, *)). (forall a b. f '(a, b)) -> f ab
        at :6:116
      Expected type: f ab
        Actual type: f '(a0, b0)
    • In the expression: x
      In an equation for ‘backward’: backward x = x
```

Conceptually, it seems like a valid program. Is there another way to implement this function? Or is this a known limitation of GHC?

Comment: Not sure if type level computation is an appropriate label when 'computing' at the type level is not the goal.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, and much to my annoyance, GHC is not yet of the opinion that `ab ~ '(Fst ab, Snd ab)`, where `Fst` and `Snd` are the type-level projections.

Comment: Dunno for sure, but at a guess: [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#t:Any) strikes again. (`Any :: (*, *)` but it is not the case that `Any ~ (a, b)` for any `a` and `b`.)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the purpose of these `forward` and `backward` functions? When would you want to use them? They just look like complicated `id` functions to me.

Comment: @AlexisKing: well, logically speaking, any true statement is a tautology... ...seriously though, I could see this as quite useful if you need to “stuff” multiple types into a single functor.

Comment: @AlexisKing, this kind of problem comes up, for example, when you need to have more than one thing in the cells of an `HList`. Ideally, we should not have to write a custom `HList` just to store an extra type, just like we can use value level to store more than one thing at each cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble, as pigworker and Daniel Wagner indicate, is that `ab` may be a "stuck type". You can sometimes work around this with type families (as I learned in [one of pigworker's papers](http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/Kleisli.pdf)):

```
type family Fst (x :: (k1, k2)) :: k1 where
  Fst '(t1, t2) = t1

type family Snd (x :: (k1, k2)) :: k2 where
  Snd '(t1, t2) = t2

backward :: forall (f :: (*, *) -> *) (ab :: (*, *)) proxy .
            proxy ab ->
            (forall (a :: *) (b :: *). f '(a, b)) ->
            f '(Fst ab, Snd ab)
backward _ x = x
```

Another option, sometimes, is to use wrappers.

```
newtype Curry f x y = Curry (f '(x,y))

data Uncurry f xy where
  Uncurry :: f x y -> f '(x, y)
```